# OAuth: Authenticating Android user on google app engine using Facebook SSO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, single-sign-on, facebook-oauth

I am trying to implement facebook SSO on my Android app. Once the user logs into the app using facebook he will make calls to my web service running on Google App Engine(GAE). Currently I am able to obtain the access_token from facebook on my android app. Then I add this access_token as a cookie to my http request to GAE . But I am not sure how would I authenticate the request from the user using the cookie, on GAE. Currently I am trying:-

```
User user = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService().getCurrentUser();
String email = user.getEmail();
```

But my GAE web service is throwing this exception:-

```
org.restlet.resource.UniformResource doCatch: Exception or error caught in resource
com.google.appengine.api.oauth.InvalidOAuthParametersException
```

Is this the correct way of authenticating the user? If yes, then what am I missing here which is causing this exception.

Thank for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

This is failing because you're not using OAuth. You're taking a Facebook connect authentication token - which also doesn't use OAuth - and attaching it to a request you're making to your App Engine app.

If you want to use OAuth with your app, you will need to authenticate to your App Engine app. If you want to reuse your Facebook credentials, you will have to use whatever API Facebook provides for verifying authentication tokens (if there is one), not the OAuth API.

Comment: Thanks Nick! Actually, I am using Facebook SSO by following instructions mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ . And according to following facebook blog post, SSO uses OAuth: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/ . Am I missing something here ?